# ASP.NET MVC - GET with one ViewModel, POST with another

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm kind of a noob so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I am loading a page successfully using Model Binding in ASP.NET MVC 2.  Now I want to use Model Binding to submit the results of a form, but I want to use a different Model that the one I loaded with.  Is this possible?  Or should I just use the same ViewModel for both purposes?

Comment: For MVC 3 and later, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15094054/11683

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's definitely possible.

The only thing to remember is the `name` attributes on your form inputs must be the same as the properties in the viewmodel.

Currently I have a hand crafted form (no strongly typed helpers) which once posted binds to a view model.

Comment: So I can't use the strongly typed helpers?  Sorry, I'm confused.

Comment: You can, as long as your properties in both view models are named the same. Eg. `viewModel1.DisplayName` & `viewModel2.DisplayName`

Comment: What if viewModel2 is a subObject of viewModel1 (as in `viewModel2.DisplayName ==> viewModel1.viewModel2.DisplayName`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. Your details controller action and create controller action are different methods so you can make them accept whatever types you want.

```cs
//
// GET /Test/12
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(new ViewModel{/*properties init*/});
}

//
// POST: /Test/Update
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(UpdateModel model)
{
    //Do something with the model
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I'm more interested in an example of the View using Model Binding.  The part you posted makes sense to me.